# How did Eclipse create their installer and exe

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

How did eclipse create their installer to their program? how it creates a .exe file?

I'm asking because eclipse is written in java and this is not a jws installer.

Comment: eclipse installer? It's just a .zip file you have to unpack. As for the launcher, I don't know.

Comment: The eclipse launcher is just a special JNLP files which start a the first frame to prepare settings/environments for the editor frame itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't use any installer because it doesn't need inject any data in registry or something.

As for the launcher take a look at the "Eclipse Boot Process" part of [this article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/)

Answer (score 1):

The eclipse launcher is just a special JNLP files which start a the first frame to prepare settings/environments for the editor frame itself

Answer (score 1):

It is build using Java but may be some c,c++ or ASM codes are used just for creating that exe file.
  :)